# Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS can´t find sensors

Tags: temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

## What I´ve done so far

```
$ sudo apt install lm-sensors
$ sudo sensors-detect
: (yes to all)
$ sudo services kmod start
$ sensors
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
$ reboot
$ sensors
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
$ sudo sensors
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
$ sudo sensors-detect
: (yes to all until here)
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `adm1025':
  * Bus `SMBus I801 adapter at e000'
    Busdriver `i2c_i801', I2C address 0x2d
    Chip `adm1025' (confidence: 6)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
adm1025
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)no

Unloading i2c-i801... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK


$ sensors
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
$ sudo nano /etc/modules
: (manually add driver module)
$ sudo service kmod start
$ sudo service kmod status
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; ven
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-10-31 21:04:56 CDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 251 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=
 Main PID: 251 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 31 21:04:54 husky-E-4000 systemd-modules-load[251]: Inserted module 'lp'
Oct 31 21:04:56 husky-E-4000 systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomple
$ sudo service kmod stop
$ sudo service kmod start
$ sudo service kmod status
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; ven
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-10-31 21:12:10 CDT; 55s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 1199 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status
 Main PID: 1199 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 31 21:12:10 husky-E-4000 systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Oct 31 21:12:10 husky-E-4000 systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
$ sensors
No sensors found!
Make sure you loaded all the kernel drivers you need.
Try sensors-detect to find out which these are.
```

## System Information

### Computer

#### Summary

```
-Computer-
Processor       : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz
Memory      : 2058MB (580MB used)
Machine Type        : Desktop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
User Name       : husky (Husky 2490)
Date/Time       : Wed 31 Oct 2018 09:43:29 PM CDT
-Display-
Resolution      : 1024x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : (Unknown)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Audio Devices-
Audio Adapter       : ICH4 - Intel 82801DB-ICH4
-Input Devices-
 Sleep Button
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
 Logitech USB Optical Mouse
-Printers-
No printers found
-SCSI Disks-
ATA Maxtor 2F040J0
HL-DT-ST RW/DVD GCC-4320B
```

#### Operating System

```
-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 4.15.0-38-generic (i686)
Version     : #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:58:23 UTC 2018
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
Distribution        : Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
-Current Session-
Computer Name       : husky-E-4000
User Name       : husky (Husky 2490)
Language        : en_US.UTF-8 (en_US)
Home Directory      : /home/husky
-Misc-
Uptime      : 43 minutes
Load Average        : 0.42, 0.52, 0.54
Available entropy in /dev/random        : 3722 bits (healthy)
```

This computer is an oldie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your computer uses the `i2c-i801` module and this module was blacklisted. However, there was a recent update which removed this module from the blacklist file at `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Execute the following commands to fix this issue:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Assuming you have made no changes to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` you should type <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when prompted to overwrite the old blacklist file with the new file.

After the upgrade is complete, run the following command to verify this change:

```
grep i2c-i801 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

This command should return nothing.

Reboot or reload your modules and then check the sensors again.